# Add new admin post page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I add a custom admin page inside Posts section in Wordpress that lists posts that has certain meta_key and its meta_value has a value?

```php
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu'); 

function my_admin_menu() { 
    add_submenu_page('edit.php', 'Posts - Image Social', 'Posts - Image Social', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?meta_key=image_social&meta_value'); 
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'restrict_events_by_meta');

function restrict_events_by_meta($q){
    if( 
        $q->is_main_query() 
        && is_admin() 
        && 'post' == $q->get('post_type') 
        && isset( $_GET['meta_key']) 
        && isset( $_GET['meta_value']) 
    ){
        $q->set('meta_key', $_GET['meta_key'] );
        $q->set('meta_value', $_GET['meta_value'] );
        $q->set('orderby', 'meta_key' );
    }
}
```